# Is there any way to stop ts-node-dev?

Tags: ts-node, ts-node-dev

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that can shut down on command. Yesterday I asked another question related to this but no one answered. So now I'm thinking is there any way to stop ts-node-dev from command line / .ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried process.exit(1)? It works in js. I think you need to install  `@types/node` for ts?

Alternatively you can use a bit of a whacky method:
You can try launching ts-node with pm2 or nodemon and in order to kill your bot try executing cli command like

```
exec("killall nodemon", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Yes I did try process.exit. It didn't work because it tried to exit node.js not ts-node

Comment: Hello, I'm still trying to pull it off with pm2 but for now I see an error about using TypeScript. Do you know how I can do it? The error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'